# Silverlight 5 AccessViolationException When reset textbox values

Tags: .net, access-violation, silverlight-5.0

I am basically gathering an object, and passing it into a method that uses that objects properties to populate on the textbox's, and select radio buttons, combobox items, and datepickers dates...

I get this error every third or forth time and repopulate all the values:

AccessViolationException :
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Any ideas?

```
 Protected Sub PopulateForms(ByVal a As OMGService.OmgApp)

    Me.txtAppTitle.Text = a.Title

    Me.txtAppVersion.Text = a.Version

    Me.txtLicenseCount.Text = a.LicenseCount.ToString()

    Me.txtAppLocation.Text = a.AppLocation

    Me.txtDocLocation.Text = a.DocLocation

    Me.txtKey.Text = a.Key

    Me.txtAppNotes.Text = a.AppNotes

    Me.cBoxAppLicType.SelectedItem = Me.cBoxAppLicType.Items.Item(a.LicenseType)

    Me.radio64.IsChecked = a.IsX64

    Me.radio86.IsChecked = IIf(Me.radio64.IsChecked, False, True)

    Me.appInfoCreatedMsg.Text = String.Format("App Info Created: {0}", a.RecordCreated.ToString())

    Me.appInfoModifiedMsg.Text = String.Format("App Info Modified: {0}", a.LastModified.ToString())

    Me.txtOldPo.Text = a.OldCastlePO

    Me.txtAltTicket.Text = a.AltirisTicketNum

    Me.txtVendorName.Text = a.VendorName

    Me.txtRepName.Text = a.VendorRepName

    Me.txtRepPhone.Text = a.VendorRepPhone

    Me.txtVendorOrderNum.Text = a.VendorOrderNumber

    Me.txtTermsCond.Text = a.TermsConditions

    Me.DateOfPurchasePicker.SelectedDate = a.DateOfPurchase

    Me.OrderInfoCreatedMsg.Text = String.Format("Order Info Created: {0}", a.OrderRecordCreated)

    Me.OrderInfoModifiedMsg.Text = String.Format("Order Info Created: {0}", a.LastModified)

    Me.txtHiddenAppID.Text = a.AppID.ToString()

    Me.txtHiddenOrderId.Text = a.OrderID.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed it by not using the SystemColors theme anymore... odd.

Comment: Why are you using that kind of monster method when you have proper data binding in Silverlight?

Comment: I guess you have a reverse method too, to populate your object from UI, which would also not be needed if using data binding.

Comment: just a quick update, the above is terrible. this is now done through databinding as it should be #facepalm.

Comment: Well done! Data binding is the way to go :)